# Is it possible to get the string inside the enclosing '<' and '>' of a tag using jquery or plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If  my question isn't clear,I don't want the outerhtml which returns all the contents inside a node.I don't want those.For example:

```html
<div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block">
  Hello!
  <div id="bar" class="something_else">
    How are you?Hope you are doing well!
  </div>
</div>
```

Now,outerHTML of 'foo' will give the whole string representation of its DOM structure.I just want

```
div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block"
```

Is it possible to get this without using regex/string matching?

Comment: I suggest you first correct your expected result. Current one has no sense.

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: So you want the opening tag of the `div`, without the `<` and `>` delimiters...? That's a really weird requirement that seems like an X/Y issue. Why do you need this?

Comment: You have the nodeName followed by a collection of attribute names and values.  So yeah you can javascript it.  But I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, what do you intend to use that for?

Comment: It's not that I don't need those delimiters.Its fine.Yeah and I need this to get the diff between two htmls.First,I am replacing the tags with custom tags ,running a diff and then restoring all those tags.I tried htmldiff.js but it doesn't work properly when there are strong tags,etc.Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using javascript element.nodeName and element.attributes to form a string:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
console.log(crazyString(foo));

function crazyString(el) {
  var a = [el.nodeName];
  var atts = el.attributes;
  for (var i=0; i < atts.length; i++) {
    a.push(atts[i].name + '="' + atts[i].value + '"');
  }
  return a.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block">
  Hello!
  <div id="bar" class="something_else">
    How are you?Hope you are doing well!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that´s the solution. I don´t understand that Johann Karlsson get 5 upvotes... I vote for your solution.

Comment: @FrankWisniewski because brittle one-liners are easily digested.

Comment: Here is the one liner : 
`document.getElementById('foo').tagName + ' ' + Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('foo').attributes).map((e) => e.name + '="' + e.value + '"').join(' ')`

Comment: only for fun and bad code...
``${foo.tagName} ${Array.from(foo.attributes).map((e) => `${e.name}="${e.value}"`).join(' ')}``

Comment: @FrankWisniewski Pros and cons to both our solutions. This for example doesn't return the exact string as OP stated (uppercase div), and might get the order of attributes wrong, while mine can easily fail on various attributes.

Comment: The editor don´t show the template literal. That must be set into template literals. But it´s only for fun....

Comment: with the spread operator it is shorter...
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/segonotujo/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the outerHTML and then parse the part you want:

```js
console.log(
    document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML.match(/<([^>]+)>/)[1]
);
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block">
  Hello!
  <div id="bar" class="something_else">
    How are you?Hope you are doing well!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree, but OP didn't want regex matching

Comment: `<div id="foo" title='<uh-oh>' ...` you simply can't parse html using regex.  Might be ok in simple, known cases.

Comment: OP: *"Is it possible to get this **without using regex**/string matching?*"

Comment: Man, it's like people never saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/621962)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```js
var element = document.getElementById("foo");

var tag = element.tagName; 
  $.each(element.attributes, function() {
    tag += " "+ this.name + '"'+ this.value+ '"';   
  });
  alert(tag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block">
  Hello!
  <div id="bar" class="something_else">
    How are you?Hope you are doing well!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using  `Array#reduce`

```js
let el = document.getElementById('foo');

let res = [].slice.call(el.attributes).reduce((a, c) => {  
  return a.concat(c.name + '="' + c.value + '"');
}, [el.tagName.toLowerCase()]).join(' ');

console.log(res)
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="something" style="width:80%; display:inline-block"></div>
```